# Prepare requires the command to have a transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am getting this error:

> Prepare requires the command to have a transaction when the connection
>   assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The
>   Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.

On the Prepare():

```
connection = new SqlConnection(dbconnectionstring);
connection.Open();
transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
SqlCommand Command1 = GetCommand1(connection);
SqlCommand Command2 = GetCommand2(connection, transaction);


private SqlCommand GetCommand1(SqlConnection connection)
{
    const string sql = @"
        INSERT INTO R_Activity(start_time, activity_num) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES(SYSDATETIME(), @ACTIVITY_NUM)
        ";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ACTIVITY_NUM", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0));
    command.Prepare();  // Error here.
    return command;
}


private SqlCommand GetCommand2(SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)
{
    const string sql = @"
        INSERT IVS_RUNHISTORY ( r_activity_id, datasource,  rundate)
                               OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
                               VALUES (@r_activity_id, @datasource, @rundate)
        ";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection, transaction);

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@datasource", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char, 4));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@rundate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime, 0));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@r_activity_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0));
    command.Prepare();
    return command;
}
```

How can I avoid that error?

My goal is to allow Command1 to run outside of the transaction such that the row will be fully written in the database as soon as the insert runs, and Command2 will wait to be fully written until a Commit().

The difference in the commands is that Command1 is like a log of what is happening and Command2 is the business logic of the Console Program.  That is, even if the business logic fails, I still want to see the log in the database.

This is a cut down sample of the code.  There are other commands that will be associated with the transaction.

[EDIT]
If I comment out the Prepare() the error moves the execution:

> ExecuteScalar requires the command to have a transaction when the
>   connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction. 
>   The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.

[EDIT]
The use case for this is: I have a table I want to update and not be subject to a rollback.  The table is a log of what the program is doing.  I want the log to be intact even if there is a ROLLBACK.

Comment: `Command2 will wait to be fully written until a Commit().` If there is only a single INSERT in the transaction there is no value in having an **explicit** transaction.

Comment: SqlServer *doesn't require* command preparation; frankly, you could remove all the `.Prepare()` here and *nothing would change*

Comment: SqlServer does not require preparation but does it benefit from preparation?

Comment: You cannot run a command *without* specifying the transaction, if there is a transaction on the connection; you **must** be all or nothing

Comment: @MichaelPotter in my experience: nope, not really - and *especially* not if you're doing it on a command that you're creating and executing once

Comment: @MarcGravell - I have an INSERT that will be executed in a loop.  Will it benefit from the Prepare()?

Comment: @MichaelPotter time it! but IMO: unlikely; and it would require you to use the same `SqlCommand` instance in the loop without changing the command-text or adding/removing parameters, but: just changing the parameter values

Comment: @MarcGravell What do you think of solving the problem with opening two connections...  Once for the transaction based commands and one for the non-transaction based commands?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? A second connection doesn't seem like the right solution for anything, and will have much more difficulty scaling. Why don't you pass all your values in one go, using a TVP, and stop using an explicit transaction in the app in the first place? Let SQL Server handle the transaction and the app deal with its success or failure.

Comment: @AaronBertrand  First I have heard of TVP, looks interesting, but I still need to insert/update multiple tables in the transaction and a couple of tables outside of the transaction so it is not a solution for this case.

Comment: A stored procedure can do all that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by opening a second connection for the transaction based SQL.

[Comments telling me I am crazy cheerfully accepted]

```
connection = new SqlConnection(dbconnectionstring);
connection.Open();
connectiont = new SqlConnection(dbconnectionstring);
connectiont.Open();
transaction = connectiont.BeginTransaction();
SqlCommand Command1 = GetCommand1(connection);
SqlCommand Command2 = GetCommand2(connectiont, transaction);


private SqlCommand GetCommand1(SqlConnection connection)
{
    const string sql = @"
        INSERT INTO R_Activity(start_time, activity_num) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES(SYSDATETIME(), @ACTIVITY_NUM)
        ";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ACTIVITY_NUM", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0));
    command.Prepare();  // Error here.
    return command;
}


private SqlCommand GetCommand2(SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)
{
    const string sql = @"
        INSERT IVS_RUNHISTORY ( r_activity_id, datasource,  rundate)
                               OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
                               VALUES (@r_activity_id, @datasource, @rundate)
        ";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection, transaction);

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@datasource", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char, 4));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@rundate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime, 0));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@r_activity_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 0));
    command.Prepare();
    return command;
}
```